# React Navigation Crash with react-native-reanimated

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated

I am facing a problem with my navigation setup after integrating the **`react-native-reanimated`** library into my React Native project. Prior to integrating **`react-native-reanimated`**, my navigation system was working fine, and I was able to navigate using the defined types without any issues. However, after adding **`react-native-reanimated`** to my project, I encountered a serious problem.

The issue occurs when interacting with the navigation stack headers' back button or when switching tabs in the bottom tab navigator. Instead of providing any error feedback, the app crashes abruptly.

I have used Flipper for debugging, and it pointed me to an error labeled "EXC_BAD_ACCESS." This error seems to be related to memory access problems. Interestingly, I only experience this issue after adding the **`react-native-reanimated`** package. When I remove this package, the problem disappears.

```
{
  "name": "DocvivoMobil",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.16",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.11",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-dropdown-select-list": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.2",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.24.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.13.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.7",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.21",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.2",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.14",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue, but none of them have worked:

1. Updated all packages to their latest versions.
2. Ensured proper linking of the **`react-native-reanimated`** library.
3. Verified that the other modules I'm using are compatible and not causing conflicts.
4. Checked the compatibility of **`react-native-reanimated`** with my React Native version.
5. Adjusted the order of packages in my **`package.json`**.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem when integrating **`react-native-reanimated`** into their navigation setup? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue in a rather interesting way: I used any Reanimated feature on any navigation screen, and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed react-native-reanimated from the project because we don't need it.

Comment: I am facing similar kind of issue when I am using navigation.reset or replace my iOS app is crashing and giving error related to EXC_BAD_ACCESS to RNReanimated.

any idea how to solve it ? @Zeeshan

Answer (score 0):

I had a passing problem after adding react-reanimated to the project
There was a simple functionality for swiping pages using a gesture-handler, as soon as I set it to reanimated when swiping, the application crashed (but the buttons worked)

```js
  const swipeBack = Gesture.Fling()
    .runOnJS(true) // this helped me
    .direction(Directions.LEFT)
    .onEnd((e) => {
      console.log("Swipe to left");
      onContinue();
    });
```